# for each row in dataframe return non zero element as array in r

Tags: r

I have a R dataframe like following

```
    client      A        B         C           D
      asd     awe     0         rty         0
      wer        0       tyu     wer        0
```

my desired dataframe is following

```
    client      A        B         C           D     recom
      asd     awe     0         rty         0      awe rty
      wer        0       tyu     wer        0      tyu wer
```

I want all non zero elements to be printed in names ccolumn
I am using following code to generare above,but it dies not seem to work

```
    df$recom= simplify2array(apply(df[2:5],1, function(x) paste(df[2:5]) [x!=0],collapse=" "))
```

Comment: Why do you need `simplify2array`? the `apply` output is a `vector`. `df$recom <- apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) paste(x[x!=0], collapse=" "))`  Also, when you call anonymous function, use `x[2:5]` instead of the whole dataset with `df[2:5]`

Comment: @akrun  I see that my answer is not different.  I had not read your comment carefully.  Why don't you add yours as an answer and I will delete mine.

Comment: @GSW It's okay.  I find two solutions using the same without acknowledging and that is why I commented.  Probably, you haven't seen it.  No problem.  Thanks for clearing it

Answer (score 1):

try:

`df$recom <- apply(df[, 2:5],1, function(x) paste(x[x!=0], collapse=" "))`

`client    A    B   C  D   recom
1    asd  awe   0 rty  0  awe rty
2    wer  0   tyu wer  0  tyu wer`

Answer (score 1):

Or a faster option would be to `paste` the elements by row and then remove the 0 values

```
df$recom <- trimws(gsub("^0 +| +0|0 +0", "", do.call(paste, df1[-1])))
df$recom
#[1] "awe rty" "tyu wer"
```

---

As we mentioned in the comments, `simplify2array` is not required with the `apply` call as the elements in each row are `paste`d together to get a `vector` as output.  In fact, in the OP's solution, instead of using the anonymous 'x' to subset and later `paste`, the full dataset i.e. `df[2:5]` was used.  So, instead it should be the one in the comments (which is similar to the one posted in the other solution)